# How to sum the values of an associative array?

Tags: php, arrays

How can I add the array elements by key? Thanks in advance!
Please find the code snippet below

```
(
    [2] => Array
        (
            [addition_price] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 0
                    [1] => 40
                    [2] => 40
                )

    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [addition_price] => Array
            (
                [0] => 100
            )

    )

)
```

**Desired result:**

> [2] = 0 + 40 + 40 = 80
>
> [3] = 100

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sum up values in multidimensional php array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23482452/sum-up-values-in-multidimensional-php-array)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try this way, i hope it works:

```
foreach($array as $key => $value){
     $sum = 0;
     foreach($value['addition_price'] as $v){
          $sum += $v;
     }
     $array[$key] = $sum;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

you should try this:

```
$array = [
    0 => [
        "addition_price" => [
            0,
            40,
            40
        ]
    ],
    1 => [
        "addition_price" => [
            100
        ]
    ],
];
foreach ($array as $key=>$value) {
    if(!empty($value['addition_price']) && is_array($value['addition_price'])){
        echo $key. " => " .array_sum($value['addition_price']). "<br>";
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Use [`array_sum`](http://php.net/array_sum) for summing up, and [`array_map`](http://php.net/array_map) to do that for every item in the array

```
$result = array_map(
     function($a) { return array_sum($a['addition_price']); }, 
     $input
);
```